# ASP MVC  -хранение строки подключения в Web.config и ошибка подключения

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Добрый день!

Изучаю MVC.

В файл Web.config добавляю строку подключения:
[image]

При работе, скажем, с вин.формами подключение идет прекрасно.

Теперь, получаю эту строку подключения в проекте:

[image]

Текст ошибки:

An error occurred while getting provider information from the database. This can be caused by Entity Framework using an incorrect connection string. Check the inner exceptions for details and ensure that the connection string is correct.

**Подскажите, пожалуйста, где в моей логике ошибка.**
Спасибо.

Comment: Я думаю для начала надо последовать совету и проверить inner exception

Comment: Причина ошибки - "Поставщик не возвратил строку ProviderManifestToken". Говорят, нужно переустановить EntutyFramework или MVC, или вообще все начиная с VS. А без этого как-то можно обойтись? Строка подключения рабочая, проверено.

Comment: Можешь попробовать подключиться к базу данных через ADO.NET, он сам сконфигурирует настройки в Web.config. Также посмотри под отладчиком, доступны ли какие-нибудь другие свойства. Там же посмотри в исключении (рядом с StackTrace) должно быть более подробное описание, что пошло не так.
Поставщика ты используешь по умолчанию или другой?

Comment: Поставщик по умолчанию.
Подключаюсь через  ADO. Создал модель, теперь цепляю на нее контроллер - при создании контроллера пишет " имя таблицы "- has no key defined. Ваще я в ступоре. Само ж создало(

Comment: Попробуйте создать подключение к базе при помощи 
var db = new "Название проекта".Models.Entities().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Возможно попробуйте такой формат строки подключения: 
`Data Source=myServerAddress;Initial Catalog=myDataBase;Trusted_Connection=True;`   детальнее на странице www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server

Comment: Пробовал. проблема решила после переустановки студии.